# Paypal In-app Billing for Android

Tags: android, paypal

I was originally going to implement Android Market in-app billing, but that turned out to be too troublesome. I decided I should try to use Paypal's. All I want to do is add a donation button inside my Android app. Has anyone seen any good tutorials? I was having a problem with finding my code for the sandbox server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like using Paypal for in-app payment is allowed by Google's Android Market Terms of Service, according to the discussion here:
   https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-mobile-xspace/paypal-app-model-android-legal-android-market#answer-186985

Answer (score 0):

You can have a donation button:
i use this for my donation buttons and have it set as a picture button:

```
`Donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/your_paypal"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });`
```

to get the link version click the email version when setting up the button.
if the donations are for you i would name the button "support the devs"